# $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] always gives primary IP of server not actual running server IP in php

Tags: php, server, ip

On my server 10 IPs are available. Each time running automatically changes the running IP among that ten IP. The below code always returns the primary IP of my server not the actual running IP of the server.

```
<?PHP
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
?>
```

How to get the actual running IP of my server?

Comment: 'SERVER_ADDR' The IP address of the server under which the current script is executing. [docs](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server). Probably you should have a look at your web servers vhost configuration. Why do IPs rotate on a single machine? Does it make sense without a load balancer and multiple hosts?

Comment: No, my scripts are running in secondary IP but SERVER_ADDR returns the main IP of my server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function getIPAddress() {  
 
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {  
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];  
    }  
 
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {  
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];  
 }  
else{  
         $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
 }  
 return $ip;
```

}